# Detecting home button click event on iPad from the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad-2

How can I detect the home button click on iPad2?

My application needs to send update the server when the home button is clicked on iPad2.

I have tried unload, resize event through jQuery, but nothing gets fired. I have tried the same on both normal browser and link from add to home screen.

Comment: shouldn't you be using jquery mobile when you are developing for the ipad2 ?

Comment: WOW what a title. Add `computers` to the list

Comment: Inform yourself about the Page Visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 2):

You can't detect a press on the home button. You could try for when the window/body loses focus, this isn't guaranteed to work though as I haven't tested it. It might also catch other events like switching tabs, closing the window etc.

Something like this *may* work

```
$('body').blur(function() {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to fire an Event if there's no such Event in Safari.
unload won't work as the Site isn't unloaded.

You can try to build some sort of heartbeat mechanism and check on your server, if a certain client has stopped sending heartbeats.

Comment: Or you can try the page visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 2):

The focus and blur events on the window are good to detect if the browser is going to or back from background.

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function(evt){
    console.log('show');
}, false);
window.addEventListener("blur", function(evt){
    console.log('hide');
}, false);
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I cannot get it to see the focus change.